# Hyperledger Fabric SDK connection profile configuration in production mode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, production-environment, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I was going through the Hyperledger fabric Node SDK tutorial to use a common connection profile given [here](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/tutorial-network-config.html).
In connection profile, there was some sensitive information such as **adminPrivateKey** and **signedCert** that are reserved for organization administrators, including creating/updating channels, installing/instantiating chaincodes. Production system should not expose such sensitive information this way.
Is there any other secure way to do administrators operation in production environment?